# Do I need to create separate service class for one function in java

Tags: java, design-patterns, class, service

I have person class and then class like

```
Countries 
Languages
```

I have separate classes for countries and langauages. I need to display all counries in drop down and all languagaes. So do I need to create a CountryService class and a languagaeService class? With functions like getLanguages and getCountries in there?

Looking for a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on the growth path you expect for this code base.

If you don't see much else being added to a `CountryService` or `LanguageService` class besides the functions you mention, then adding 2 new classes may be over-engineering the solution. In this case it may be better to do something more along the lines of **adding a static method** `getLanguages` to the `Language` class, and `getCountries` to the `Country` class

If you see your self expanding the role and functionality a CountryService and a LanguageService class then this approach would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution isn't wrong, but generally methods like `getAvailableCountries()` and `getAvailableLanguages()` are declared as static methods in their respective classes. That way, you can use them like this:

```
List<Country> lc = Country.getAvailableCountries();
List<Language> ll = Language.getAvailableLanguages();
```

---

Are you saving these objects in a database? In that case, I would use either of the following designs:

- The object is responsible for saving itself:

  ```
  new Country("United States").save();
  new Language("English").save();
  ```
- The class is responsible for saving the object:

  ```
  Country.save(new Country("United States"));
  Language.save(new Language("English"));
  ```

Comment: so it means all static methods should be in respective class , what about add conutry , delete country functions

Comment: Basically, yeah, there's no reason to have a `CountryService` class whose only function is to hold country functions; adding them to the `Country` class makes perfect sense, because that's the first place you'd search for methods that operate on countries.

Comment: i am using mysql and hibernate. so it means i need to define function save() in that class